# How to Uninstall MongoDb-Server on CentOS

Tags: mongodb, centos, uninstallation

I have installed a mongodb instance once, but it stops running for a reason that I could not managed to solve. So I installed MongoDb 3.4 by using [offical docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/). There are 5 modules according to the installer. One of them is **mongodb-org-server** which install **mongod** (mongo daemonized). When I run the command:

```
sudo yum install -y mongodb-org
```

It installs all of modules except mongodb-org-server. It says it's installed. However, when I run mongod, I get there is no such a command. After that I tried to remove all of the modules:

```
sudo yum erase $(rpm -qa | grep mongodb-org)
```

It does not manage to remove mongodb-org-server and throws the error below:

```
Running Transaction
Erasing: mongodb-org-3.4.1-1.el6.x86_64                                                                                                                                1/5
error reading information on service mongod: No such file or directory
error: %preun(mongodb-org-server-3.4.1-1.el6.x86_64) scriptlet failed, exit status 1
Error in PREUN scriptlet in rpm package mongodb-org-server
```

How I can fix this? I'll glad for your helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed the issue. Reinstalled the server package and deleted successfully.

```
sudo yum reinstall -y mongodb-org-server.x86_64
```